# Redefinee the binary operator + with parametred class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have my class Polynome but i have some porblem when i want to redefine the + operator.

```
#ifndef __POLYNOME_HPP__
#define __POLYNOME_HPP__

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Polynome {

    private :
        map<int, T> _coef;
    public :
        Polynome<T>(): _coef() {

        }

        Polynome<T>(Polynome<T>& pol):_coef(pol._coef) {

        }

        Polynome<T>(const T arrayOfT[]) {
            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arrayOfT)/sizeof(arrayOfT[0]); i++) {
                _coef.insert(pair<int, T>(i, arrayOfT[i]));
            }
        }

        Polynome<T>(const set< pair<int, T> > s) {
            typename set< pair<int,T> >::iterator it;
            for(it = s.begin(); it!=s.end(); ++it) {
                _coef.insert(*it);
            }
        }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Polynome pol) {
            typename map<int,T>::iterator it;
            for (it=pol._coef.begin(); it!=pol._coef.end(); ++it) {
                if(it->first != 0) {
                    os << it->second << "x^" << it->first << " + ";
                }
            }
            os << " 0 " << endl;
            return os;
        }

        T evaluation(int x) {
            T result =0;

            typename map<int, T>::iterator it;

            for(it = _coef.begin(); it != _coef.end(); ++it) {


                result += pow(it->second, it->first) * x;

            }
            return result;
        }

        T& operator[](int indice) {
            return _coef[indice];
        }

        Polynome<T> derivatative() const {
            Polynome derivativePol;

            typename map<int, T>::iterator it;
            for(it = _coef.begin(); it != _coef.end(); ++it) {
                if(it->frist >= 1) {
                    pair<int, T> derivativePair = pair<int, T>(it->first - 1, it->first * it->second);
                    derivativePol.insert(derivativePair);
                }
            }

            return derivativePol;
        }

        friend Polynome<T> operator+(Polynome<T>& p, Polynome<T>& p2) {
            Polynome<T> pResult(p);
            typename map<int, T>::iterator it;
            for(it = p._coef.begin(); it != p._coef.end(); ++it) {

                pair<int, T> newPair = pair<int, T>(it->first, it->second + p2[it->first]);
                pResult._coef.insert(newPair);

            }

            return pResult;
        }
};
#endif
```

The compilator gives me the following error :

> Polynome.cpp:32:19: error: no matching function for call to 
>   ‘Polynome::Polynome(Polynome)’
>
> Polynome.cpp:32:19: note: candidates are: In file included from
>   Polynome.cpp:1:0: Polynome.hpp:30:9: note:
>   Polynome::Polynome(std::set >) [with T = int]
>            Polynome(const set< pair > s) {
>            ^ Polynome.hpp:30:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Polynome’ to ‘std::set,
>   std::less >, std::allocator >
>
> > ’ Polynome.hpp:24:9: note: Polynome::Polynome(const T*) [with T = int]
> >              Polynome(const T arrayOfT[]) {
> >              ^ Polynome.hpp:24:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Polynome’ to ‘const int*’ Polynome.hpp:20:9: note:
> >     Polynome::Polynome(Polynome&) [with T = int]
> >              Polynome(Polynome& pol):_coef(pol._coef) {
> >              ^ Polynome.hpp:20:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Polynome’ to ‘Polynome&’ Polynome.hpp:16:9: note:
> >     Polynome::Polynome() [with T = int]
> >              Polynome(): _coef() {
> >              ^ Polynome.hpp:16:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided Polynome.hpp:37:25: error:   initializing argument 2 of
> >     ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Polynome)’
> >              friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Polynome pol) {

wich is related to this line in my main :
     cout << pol + pol2 << endl;

Where is the problem ?

EDIT 1: I changed my operator + signature and it's not working anymore.
I have :

```
friend Polynome<T> operator+(const Polynome<T>& p,const Polynome<T>& p2) {
            Polynome<T> pResult(p);
            typename map<int, T>::iterator it;
            for(it = p2._coef.begin(); it != p2._coef.end(); ++it) {


                pair<int, T> newPair = pair<int, T>(it->first, it->second + p[it->first]);
                pResult._coef.insert(newPair);

            }

            return pResult;
        }
```

But then the compiler answer this :

> Polynome.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Polynome operator+(const
>   Polynome&, const Polynome&)’: Polynome.cpp:32:19:   required
>   from here Polynome.hpp:83:20: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand
>   types are ‘std::map,
>   std::allocator > >::iterator {aka
>   std::_Rb_tree_iterator >}’ and
>   ‘std::map, std::allocator > >::const_iterator {aka
>   std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}’)
>                for(it = p2._coef.begin(); it != p2._coef.end(); ++it) {
>                       ^ Polynome.hpp:83:20: note: candidates are: In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/map:60:0,
>                    from Polynome.hpp:5,
>                    from Polynome.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:172:12: note:
>   std::_Rb_tree_iterator >&
>   std::_Rb_tree_iterator >::operator=(const
>   std::_Rb_tree_iterator >&)
>        struct _Rb_tree_iterator
>               ^ /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:172:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::map, std::allocator >
>
> > ::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}’ to ‘const std::_Rb_tree_iterator >&’ /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:172:12: note:
> >     std::_Rb_tree_iterator >&
> >     std::_Rb_tree_iterator
> >     ::operator=(std::_Rb_tree_iterator >&&) /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:172:12: note:   no known
> >     conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::map,
> >     std::allocator > >::const_iterator {aka
> >     std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}’ to
> >     ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator >&&’ In file
> >     included from Polynome.cpp:1:0: Polynome.hpp:86:78: error: passing
> >     ‘const Polynome’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘T&
> >     Polynome::operator [with T = int]’ discards qualifiers
> >     [-fpermissive]
> >                      pair newPair = pair(it->first, it->second + p[it->first]);

Why ?

Comment: `sizeof(arrayOfT)`: surprise, `arrayOfT` is a pointer!  This won't do what you want.

Comment: But i have seen this in a stack overflow post to get the size of an array, is it false ?

Comment: @BobReynolds Under certain circumstances, yes. Under other circumstances, no. [This may help](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/)

Comment: `__POLYNOME_HPP__` is an identifier that is reserved to the implementation. Unless you're writing the standard library for a compiler, your program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor should take a reference to `const` object:

```
Polynome(const Polynome<T>& pol):_coef(pol._coef) {

    }
```

Or better, follow the Rule of Zero and don't declare the copy constructor at all.

Comment: Nice this is working. But now i want to change the signature of my + operator to friend Polynome<T> operator+(const Polynome<T>& p, const Polynome<T>& p2). and it tells me  error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<int, int, std::less<int> etc...

Comment: I added my precedent in my first Edit

Comment: You need to use a `const_iterator` instead of just `iterator`.